# Ayuda con Query en django

Tags: python, django

tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
 comision = comisiones_pagadas.objects.values('codigo_proceso','fecha_pago','doctor_id').order_by('-fecha_pago').distinct()
```

Al momento de pasar 'comision' al template no puedo presentar el nombre del doctor: es decir. comision.doctor.nombres ya que doctor_id es llave foránea de la tabla Doctores, al parecer la consulta no la obtiene como un objeto sino como un diccionario de valores, como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Para eso son los [Serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la consulta se está usando el método [`.values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses) que sólo deja los campos que listas como parámetro `'codigo_proceso','fecha_pago','doctor_id'`, ahí es donde tienes que agregar el campo `doctor__nombre` (observa que es doble guión bajo porque se está seleccionando el campo nombre del objeto `Doctor.nombre` relacionado.

Tu consulta debería quedar así:

```
comision = comisiones_pagadas.objects.values('codigo_proceso','fecha_pago','doctor_id', 'doctor_name').order_by('-fecha_pago').distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola cuando hace la query solo tienes el id del doctor, no se que tipo de relacion que tienes comisiones con doctor si es OneToOne puede trata de acceder al valor del nombre del doctor `doctor__nombre`, si es ManyToMany puedes guardarlo en una variable aparte haciendo `doctores = comision.doctor.all()`